# How to draw stroke inside a circle?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Is there an easy way to draw stroke inside a circle (without drawing 2 circles and similar workarounds)? If I do it this way:

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(200, 200, 93, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, true);
context.fillStyle = '#FF6A6A';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 20;
context.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
context.stroke();
```

I get this:

[image]

The stroke is partially drawn outside the figure (marked by green circles) while I need it inside.

Comment: this is due to your lineWidth  = 20. put this to 1 and you will see that it's not outside the figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the radius to compensate for the line width:

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(200, 200, 93, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, true);
context.fillStyle = '#FF6A6A';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 20;
context.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
context.beginPath();

// the radius of 93 - half the line width
context.arc(200, 200, 93-10, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, true);

context.stroke();
```

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/qamuwumiri/edit?html,js,output